# Search any part of two autofiltered columns with textbox

Tags: excel, textbox, excel-2010, autofilter, vba

I'm trying to search for results in either one of two autofiltered columns (project number, and project name) using a text box. My code is as follows;

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()

Application.Calculation = xlManual

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox3.Value & "*", Operator:=xlOr

On Error Resume Next

If Range("B7:B1307").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count = 0 Then
Call ClearAllFilters

  ActiveSheet.Range("B7:B1307").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"

 Selection.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox3.Value & "*", Operator:=xlOr
 End If
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
 End Sub
```

I want it to look in one column, and if it finds no results then it needs to search in the other column.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What problems are you getting ? Isn't the Range....count = 0 working ? Be more specific

Comment: Sorry what's happening with the above code is autofilter field 6 is returning the search query (with no results) but autofilter field 5 is performing a search query for *. I need it to search through autofilter field 6, and if there are no results, for it to search through autofilter field 5.

Hope this makes sense!

Thank you

Comment: Your filter looks weird.. could you post a screenshot of your data please?

Comment: (http://s797.photobucket.com/user/magandaangels/library/Stack Exchange Screengrabs?evt=email_share)

Argh I can't get the link to work! If you can copy paste the link it'll work sorry. 

As you can see, searching by project name works fine, but searching by project number returned no results. Excuse my poor photo editing skills!

Comment: And now I can't edit my previous comment. Apologies.

[http://s797.photobucket.com/user/magandaangels/library/Stack%20Exchange%20Screengrabs#/user/magandaangels/library/Stack%20Exchange%20Screengrabs?page=1&_suid=136504271038305909143010307589]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually just created a new column which concatenates the two columns of information and  then searches that instead - it works fine.

I'm still interested in finding out what's wrong with the above code though.